# Ag-grid + Angular 6 - Display nested array in column

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a list of users and each user has several roles as array. I use ag-grid to display all users along with their roles, but it looks like ag-grid does not work with my data structure. So what is the best way that I can display all user roles for each user on grid table?

data structure:

```
[
 {
  userId: ''
  username: '',
  userRoles: [
    {roleId: '', roleName: ''},
    ...
  ]
 },
 ...
]
```

Comment: In what format do you want the roles to be shown? For example, do you want to show "admin,manager,user" as a simple comma-delimited string of role names, or do you want to show something with more "structure"?

Comment: The role names can be join strings in one line, but I already figured it out myself, if you have solution, please share, it's good to learn.

Comment: I use the `ColDef.valueGetter` property to set the column value to a comma-delimited string containing the values:
`const colDef: ColDef = this.grid.columnApi.getColumn('skillLevels').getColDef();
colDef.valueGetter = this.getSkillLevels;`
(where `this.getSkillLevels` returns a string containing the comma-delimited values).

Comment: @Andy King Yep, I use similar way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the best way would be to create a column group (collapsible) and put info to it.

```
  {
    headerName: 'Roles',
    children: [
        {
            headerName: "Top Role", field: "topRole", columnGroupShow: 'closed', width: 100, 
            cellRenderer: () => { return 'SuperAdmin'; }
        },
        {
            headerName: "Role: 1", columnGroupShow: 'open', width: 150,
            cellRenderer: () => { return 'SuperAdmin'; }
        },
        {
            headerName: "Role: 2", columnGroupShow: 'open', width: 150,
            cellRenderer: () => { return 'Support'; }
        }
    ]
  }
```

Here is a simple example: https://plnkr.co/edit/i3somDDT9Xdnln32xUy1?p=preview

You can define the single field to display top role from the existing and then via collapse button display all user roles.

[More details about column groups](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/)

Comment: Thank you for nice solution. In my case, I just make role names as join strings with commas then put them all in one column each row.